# How do I upgrade gunicorn3 to use python3.8 instead of python3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using a basic Ubuntu 18.04 VPS and I've been using gunicorn3 for a while. I've decided to upgrade to python3.8, however, it's unclear how to make gunicorn3 run python3.8 applications. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's a package for this called `gunicorn3` (this was tested on ubuntu)

`sudo apt-get install gunicorn3`

then running the following command should work and run gunicorn with python3:

`gunicorn3 --log-level debug --bind 0.0.0.0:30443 server:app`

Comment: I'm already using gunicorn3. I want it to use python3.8 instead of python3.6.

Comment: maybe try this then `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall gunicorn`

Comment: After running that command and trying to restart my server, this error occurs: `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gunicorn==19.7.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application`. Any idea of a fix?